# Bootstrap multi select optgroup with one element not working properly

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

Bootstrap multi select with opt group is not working properly when there is only one option inside optgroup. When I check Option 3.1 (in my example) all the optgroups above it get selected.

Please refer the following [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ets8j23k/3/) for the example.

Moreover is it possible to give only option, if optgroup has one element inside it? Like this:

```
<option value="Option 3.1">Option 3.1</option>
```

instead of

```
<optgroup label="Group 3">
   <option value="Option 3.1">Option 3.1</option>
</optgroup>
```

I am using [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) with collapsible opt groups.

Please help me in solving this issue.

**Edit**

Even if I select both the options in Group 2, Group 1 opt group also gets selected.

Comment: try this https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/680

Comment: @JYoThI it worked. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: small suggestion search more. if your not getting answer then post the question . say thanks to google . glad to help you

Comment: @JYoThI sure I will do more searching. (I replaced the js file with the one given in Bootstrap Multiselect documentation and that seemed to work too.) [Updated Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ets8j23k/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it you need just to make a little modification in bootstrap-multiselect.js.

**change this:**

```
n.prevAll('.multiselect-group').find('input').prop('checked', i);
```

**to this:**

```
n.prevAll('.multiselect-group:first').find('input').prop('checked', i);
```

As per user comment i'm posting solution link here for future user reference .

[Problems with optgroups and filter](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/680)